# How we can compare two coefficients of one linear regression?

Tags: regression, t-test, linear-model

I have this regression model,

$$\hat{Y}=\hat{a}X_1+\hat{b}X_2+\hat{c}$$

Both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are significant at 0.01 level.
$X_1$ and $X_2$ have a same unit.
Now I want to find a test that tells me whether $\hat{a}$ is significantly higher than  $\hat{b}$ or not? Can I use a simple t-test for this comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a t-test!

Since regression coefficients are asymptotically Normal, their linear combination is also asymptotically Normal. First, notice that the test $H_0: \hat{a} = \hat{b}$ is equivalent to $H_0: \hat{a} - \hat{b} = 0$. Then you can get a null distribution on $\hat{a}-\hat{b}$,

$$\hat{a} - \hat{b} \sim N(0, Var(\hat{a}) + Var(\hat{b}) - 2Cov(\hat{a},\hat{b}))$$

Which means you can use a t-test with $n-3$ degrees of freedom on the test statistic,

$$\frac{\hat{b} - \hat{a}}{\sqrt{Var(\hat{a}) + Var(\hat{b}) - 2Cov(\hat{a},\hat{b}))}}$$.

Comment: It may be a dump question but how can I find Cov of these two?

Comment: That's not the correct result in `R`: `cov.unscaled` equals $(X^\prime X)^{-1}$.  That matrix needs to be multiplied by an estimate of the residual variance in order to be an estimated covariance matrix.  Instead, use `vcov(object)` to extract the variance-covariance matrix of the parameter estimate contained in `object`. If you would like to confirm this, compare `sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))` to the "Std. Error" column produced by `summary`.

Comment: You can do this in R. If object is the name of your lm object, vcov(object).

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat thank you for your help. just one more question. 'n' is the number of original observations?